# How to make double line chart not rounded in the end (how to change cap style)?

Tags: excel, vba

When I create a line chart in Excel and change line style to double, I can see something similar to the image below:

[image]

As you can see the beggining and ending are rounded. I want to get rid of that, so it looks like this:

[image]

It can be done by changing line "cap type". I have tried exploring Series.Format.Line methods and properties but all I can do is modify beggining/ending arrows, there is no property/method for cap. I have also tried to use excel macro recorder to try and somehow expose this property/method but I have not been successful. I have also tried to search through various Excel/VBA forums but nothing helped.

Anyone able to help with my issue? I am looking for solution in VBA and VB.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this property is not exposed in VBA, so probably you are out of luck.

According to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/577b74db-9f9d-400c-a419-1999809922da/change-chart-data-series-line-format-cap-type-in-vba:

> The cap type and join type are not exposed in the VBA object model in Excel 2007 and 2010 (I don't know about Excel 2013), so the only way to set them in VBA is using the notoriously flaky SendKeys to control the Format Data Series dialog.

The article talks about office 2010, but I coudn't find any clues that this changed later.

The object that should have this information is the `Format.Line`-property of a data series or data point (class is `LineFormat`), but it shows no cap-property.

[image]

The (not so) funny thing is that the enumeration for the possible values is available in VBA:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time to do a research alongside me. I have also tried to research this issue further but it looks like it is not possible. I have accepted your answer in case somebody would be looking for the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sequence of formatting (example of formatting the first series):

```
    Dim testSeries As Series
    Set testSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)

    With testSeries.Format.Line
        .DashStyle = msoLineSquareDot
        .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        .Style = msoLineThinThin
    End With
```